# Postfix SMTP Relay Access Denied

Tags: postfix

I know that there are already many similar queries on this site, but I could not find a solution for myself in any of them. I have postfix version 3.6.4 configured for smtp. I need it to forward mail to recipients only from google. But when I try to send the mail, I get an error:

```
Jun  7 12:23:01 ubuntu-2gb-hel1-1 postfix/smtpd[20535]: connect from mail-wm1-f72.google.com[209.85.128.72]
Jun  7 12:23:01 ubuntu-2gb-hel1-1 postfix/smtpd[20535]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wm1-f72.google.com[209.85.128.72]: 454 4.7.1 <email@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<email@example.com> to=<email@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wm1-f72.google.com>
```

When I add the Google IP address(example: 209.85.128.0/24) to the mynetworks section, everything works.
But it's not convenient, because I don't know all the Google addresses. Therefore, I would like to limit access by the domain name Google (example:mail-wm1-f72.google.com). To override all google subdomains I used regexp but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

[image: main.cf]

trusted_domain

```
/.*\.google.com/
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text you can cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the configuration file "/etc/postfix/main.cf":

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = google_domains
google_domains = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/google_domains

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   ...
   check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/google_domains
   check_client_access regexp:/etc/postfix/google_domains
   ...
```

Create the file /etc/postfix/google_domains and add the following line:

```
/^.*\.google\.com$/   google_domains
```

Reload Postfix to apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this option didn't work for me. I restricted access by subnet using google article : https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en